# how to get values from initautocomplete form to initmap

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have made this code:

```js
function initialize() {
  initMap();
  initAutocomplete();
}
var map, marker;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11.2,
      center: {lat: 40.64, lng: 22.945},
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
    });
  }
  
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  locality: 'long_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  street_number: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
  }
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
  } else marker.setMap(null);
  marker.setOptions({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  
  
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Γράψτε τη διεύθυνσή σας" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>

<div id="address">
  <div id="row">
    <div class="slimField-left-3">
    <label class="label">Οδός</label>
      <input class="field" id="route" required="required" placeholder="Οδός"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slimField-right-1">
    <label class="label">Αριθμός</label>
      <input class="field" id="street_number" required="required" placeholder="Αριθμός"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="row">
    <div class="slimField-left">
    <label class="label">Περιοχή</label>
      <input method="get" list="locality-browsers" class="field" id="locality" required="required" placeholder="Περιοχή"/>
      <datalist id="locality-browsers">
      </datalist>
    </div>
    <div class="slimField-left">
    <label class="label">T.K.</label>
      <input method="get" list="postalcode-browsers" class="field" id="postal_code" maxlength="5" required="required" placeholder="Τ.Κ."/>
      <datalist id="postalcode-browsers">
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<input id="address-confirmation-btn" type="submit" class="btn" value="Η ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΗ ΕΙΝΑΙ ΣΩΣΤΗ">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize&language=el&region=GR" defer></script>
```

I made it work to get both, the fields and the marker on map, to get the values from the autocomplete, but I can't make the market move if I change the values inside the forms, can anyone help me with this?

Some values are in Greek but you can see what those mean once you enter the autocomplete address.

For example you can enter an address at the top form(autocomplete) and after the field get the value, in case you change the address number, I need to make it change in the map too.

DEMO: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spawn8/9vr0uywf/42/)

Comment: see a DEMO here: https://jsfiddle.net/spawn8/9vr0uywf/42/

Comment: The fiddle adds a marker at the selected location and centers the map there (I tried "New York, NY" and "Philadelphia, PA").  What isn't it doing that you expect? ([my version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zp4a3j9c/))

Comment: i need the map to get values from field too, for example if you enter you location and then you change the street number here 'Αριθμός' it must update the pin on the map

Comment: So you need to put the address back together and geocode it (or autocomplete it) when any of the fields change, then move the marker based on the result.  What have you tried to implement that?

Comment: i am trying to create something like this: https://www.coffeeisland.gr/

Comment: insert some valies and click "DELIVERY", then if you change any value at the fields, it updates the map

Answer (score 0):

The website you've [linked](https://www.coffeeisland.gr/) uses the [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to achieve this.

Try adding the below code in your app for a simple example you may use for guidance. It just adds change event listeners to your text fields that will geocode the values from those fields and update your map and marker accordingly.

Hoping it helps point you in the right direction.

```
var map, marker, geocoder;

function initialize() {
  initMap();
  initAutocomplete();
  initFieldListeners();
}

function initFieldListeners() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  document.getElementById("route").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("street_number").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("locality").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("postal_code").addEventListener("change", geocode);
}

function geocode() {
  var address = document.getElementById('route').value + " " + 
  document.getElementById('street_number').value + "," +
  document.getElementById('locality').value + " " +
  document.getElementById('postal_code').value;

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (!marker) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else marker.setMap(null);
      marker.setOptions({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit** for additional question on how to auto-correct the input with its `long_name`:

```
  for(let i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++){

      if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] === "route"){
        document.getElementById('route').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      }
      if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] === "locality"){
        document.getElementById('locality').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! You are the best!!! thank you!!!
Something more, do you know how can to make it auto correct the fields?
For example, if i enter the street name with some letter wrong to correct it and change it to Greek, like coffeeisland.gr does!

Comment: Sure, see my edit. :) You can just loop through the address_components array and change the values of the text fields with the long_name for the appropriate type.

Comment: aw yes!!! :D i didnt saw that! thank you!
Once i found you and you are awesome! Is it possible by changing the values at fields to get the full informations back to autocomplete?
and something more, is it possible to move the marker and get the values at fields and autocomplete?

Comment: i know i am asking a lot, but i am trying to make it work 2 weeks and finally i found someone that can help me! Thank you! :D

Comment: No worries I can help you out further, but please (1) post a new question that describes in detail what exactly you need since it's not clear from your comment above, and (2) for your own self-learning attempt to implement this yourself first.

Comment: I tried a lot but i am not so familiar with java, i do what i can and trying to learn as i go! I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064316/autocomplete-address-fields-values-with-map-relocation Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at your question in 2 days time if no one else has been able to resolve your issue.

Comment: Heya @LefterisPapastavrou friendly reminder, if this answer solved or helped you solve your issue please [accept or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).