# Autocomplete address fields values with map relocation

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, autocomplete

I have got the autocomplete address fields from google and made them locate the marker in map, by changing the fields it re-locate the mark on map,

1) is it possible by changing the values at address fields to get the full information back to autocomplete bar too?

2) is it possible to move the marker on map to change the address fields and get the full information bar to autocomplete?

```
var map, marker, geocoder;

function initialize() {
  initMap();
  initAutocomplete();
  initFieldListeners();
}

function initFieldListeners() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  document.getElementById("route").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("street_number").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("city").addEventListener("change", geocode);
  document.getElementById("postal_code").addEventListener("change", geocode);
}

function geocode() {
  var address = document.getElementById('route').value + " " + 
  document.getElementById('street_number').value + "," +
  document.getElementById('city').value + " " +
  document.getElementById('postal_code').value;

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (!marker) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else marker.setMap(null);
      marker.setOptions({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
        for(let i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++){

      if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] === "route"){
        document.getElementById('route').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      }
      if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] === "city"){
        document.getElementById('city').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
      }
  }
    }
  });
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11.2,
      center: {lat: 40.64, lng: 22.945},
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false
    });
  }

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  city: 'long_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  street_number: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
  }
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
  } else marker.setMap(null);
  marker.setOptions({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {


    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}



// START Force the dropdown to select!!!
// Find all inputs on the DOM which are bound to a datalist via their list attribute.
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[list]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  // When the value of the input changes...
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var optionFound = false,
      datalist = this.list;
    // Determine whether an option exists with the current value of the input.
    for (var j = 0; j < datalist.options.length; j++) {
        if (this.value == datalist.options[j].value) {
            optionFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
  });
}
// END Force the dropdown to select!!!
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                    {types: ['(regions)'], componentRestrictions: {'country': "gr"}});
```

Comment: 1) Your question is too broad / unclear 2) You need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue (including your HTML, CSS, etc.) and 3) Please limit your question to **one** question, explain what your code does, what doesn't work and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it is possible. Its just a matter of reassembling the address components in the properly formatted way into a string, and replacing the value of the `pac_input` DOM :

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById("pac-input").value = reassembledAddress;
      document.getElementById("pac-input").focus();
      //autocomplete.setTypes(types);
});
```

2) You can use `getPosition()` method of the `google.maps.Marker` class to get the LatLng of your draggable marker, and feed that coordinates into a [Reverse Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) request.